# MySQL stored procedure privileges from external call

Tags: python, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that requires using "UPDATE" commands. When the procedure is run from within the MySQL workbench it executes correctly. When calling the procedure from an external Python script, the final update statement does not execute.

I am logging into the database with the same account from the Python script and to the workbench.

There are previous update statements that work in the procedure when called from Python.

Update statement that work from Python:

```
update filelocations set cluster_id=NULL;
```

Update statement that does **NOT** work from Python:

```
update searchdata set cluster_id=(select cluster_id from km_data where ID =         searchdata.TweetID);
```

The procedure is using "root" as definer, and I am logging in as root. Root has all the privileges so I am stuck as to what to investigate next!

CODE:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `overallKmeans`(tweet_limit int, cluster_num   int)
BEGIN

truncate table km_data;

update searchdata set cluster_id=NULL;
update filelocations set cluster_id=NULL;
```

Call statement (used in workbench and Python):

```
CALL `tweets`.`overallKmeans`(<{tweet_limit int}>, <{cluster_num int}>);
```

There is no error message given with this, it simply does not update the values required. Leaving them as the originals. The procedure seems to complete as normal.

Here is the create statement for km_data:

```
CREATE TABLE `km_data` (
`primaryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`lat` double DEFAULT NULL,
`lng` double DEFAULT NULL,
`cluster_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primaryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=383 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The field "cluster_id" is the one trying to be updated in "searchdata". This is the only update that doesn't work from Python.

Comment: could you provide some code.

Comment: It's weird. It works inside of mysql. The only issue might be in the python code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. Seems to work when you "commit" your changes subsequent to calling the stored procedure.

Steps:
1. Cursor.callproc("xyz")
2. Cursor.execute("commit")

I picked it from someone who was facing similar issue with pyodbc...

Thanks,
M